# Jolt spec for filtering JSON records in an array which has same value for two different fields in same object

Tags: arrays, json, filter, transformation, jolt

Input JSON :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "a",
    "token": "x"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "b",
    "token": "xx"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "xxx",
    "token": "xxx"
  }
]
```

Need output json:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "xxx",
    "token": "xxx"
  }
]
```

Expectation is Need records only where name and token has same value. Please help to form a jolt spec file for this filter

Also after filter. is it possible to sort the objects in output array wrt name value in descending manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation specs

```json
[
  { // generate nodes by the values of "name" and "token" attributes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@name.@token"
      }
    }
  },
  { // match the values of the outer and inner keys of the objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,&)": "[]" // traverse two levels up the tree
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the keys of the objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The objects might be sorted ascendingly by adding a simple **sort** transformation just before the last **shift** transformation such as

```json
{ 
  "operation": "sort"
}
```

but unfortunately there's no straightforward method to sort descendingly.

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]